# Transaction Management in Spring Neo4j Rest

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, graph-databases

I am using spring-data-neo4j-rest framework to access Neo4j Rest APIs(hosted on a remote server). How can I manage transaction while using this?

My code is something like this.
If query2 is failing, is there any way that I can rollback query1.

```
Transaction tx = neo4jTemplate.getGraphDatabase().beginTx();
try {
    Result<Map<String, Object>> results1 = neoTemplate.query(query1, null);
    Result<Map<String, Object>> results2 = neoTemplate.query(query2, null);
    Result<Map<String, Object>> results3 = neoTemplate.query(query3, null);
    tx.success();
}
catch(Exception e){
    tx.failure();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use @Transactional
You missed tx.close() at the end

You need to use 3.3.x with SpringCypherRestGraphDatabase in your config